# función de js con varios condicionales

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber si esta funcion en la cual ejecuto  mediante un onkeyup es la encargada de que lo que le paso por la variable se aplique a cada if dependiendo del id y los id los hago manualmente yo habia pensado en hacer un for y usar el i del for para cambiar los ids y que fuera dinamico pero no resulta en nada

```js
function buscar() {
    var textoBusqueda = $("input#busqueda1").val();
    if (textoBusqueda !== "") {
        $.post("buscar.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(mensaje) {// buscar.php es la pagina donde instanciaremos la clase y haremos la busqueda
            //$("#resultadoBusqueda").html(mensaje);// mensaje es el que se va a retornar al hacer la busqueda en la funcion de la clase claculadora
        $('#resultadoBusqueda1').val(mensaje);//.val para añadir valores de texto o variables a un input 
   }); 
    } else { 
        
        $('#resultadoBusqueda1').val('escriba quimico') ;// resultado busqueda es el contenedor donde mostramos el mensaje que es lo que hemos buscado con la palabra o nos aha devuelto la busqueda
 };
        // 2 busqueda de los input
        var textoBusqueda1 = $("input#busqueda2").val();
    if (textoBusqueda1 !== "" ) {
        $.post("buscar.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda1}, function(mensaje1) {// buscar.php es la pagina donde instanciaremos la clase y haremos la busqueda
            //$("#resultadoBusqueda").html(mensaje);// mensaje es el que se va a retornar al hacer la busqueda en la funcion de la clase claculadora
        $('#resultadoBusqueda2').val(mensaje1);//.val para ayadir valores de texto o variables a un input 
   }); 
    } else { 
        
        $('#resultadoBusqueda2').val('escriba quimico') ;// resultado busqueda es el contenedor donde mostramos el mensaje que es lo que hemos buscado con la palabra o nos aha devuelto la busqueda
 };
        // 3 busqueda de los input
        var textoBusqueda2 = $("input#busqueda3").val();
    if (textoBusqueda2 !== "" ) {
        $.post("buscar.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda2}, function(mensaje2) {// buscar.php es la pagina donde instanciaremos la clase y haremos la busqueda
            //$("#resultadoBusqueda").html(mensaje);// mensaje es el que se va a retornar al hacer la busqueda en la funcion de la clase claculadora
        $('#resultadoBusqueda3').val(mensaje2);//.val para ayadir valores de texto o variables a un input 
   }); 
    } else { 
        
        $('#resultadoBusqueda3').val('escriba quimico') ;// resultado busqueda es el contenedor donde mostramos el mensaje que es lo que hemos buscado con la palabra o nos aha devuelto la busqueda
 };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Saludos Guillermo, bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo leer estos 2 enlaces: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y obtengas tu primera medalla, revisa también cómo preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y te sugiero que redactes un título apropiado porque es demasiado genérico. Describe el escenario, lo que tienes, el error y el resultado que esperas si todo sale bien. Edita tu pregunta y aquí te ayudamos :D

Comment: Puedes aclarar un poco mas la pregunta? Gracias

Comment: @IvanIsayenko lo que quiero es recoger ediante jquery los valores de los inputs y despues procesar eso por ajax para mandarlo a una pagina php que se encarge de devolver la informacion. lo que yo quiero es saber si se puede hacer un bucle for para repetir el codigo que tengo arriba  los if y else y hacer dinamico el id mediante el bucle for con la cuenta del propio bluque

Comment: Entiendo. Podrias añadir tu codigo `html` para verlo mejor? Gracias :)